# How is Android jniLibs folder created?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am looking at an old sample android project in eclipse and i see a folder jniLibs under app/src folder and into app/build/intermediates. It also has a subfolder armeabi and some .so files in it.

I am trying to create a similar project to android studio but this folder does not exist.  When i try to run my new app it throws an error because it can't find one of the .so files in this folder.

How is the folder created? Does the IDE generate it or i have to create and add the .so files inside it manually? Are those .so file generated, too or someone imported them manually in the sample project?

Comment: Have you taken a look at NDK samples from Google to see how they structure their JNI code?  See: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `jniLibs` folder yourself. 
The correct path would be

`src/main/jniLibs`

and put your external libraries

Other folders/files at this level are

`src/main/java`
`src/main/res`
`src/main/res/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Is it always imported manually or can it be generated automatically too somehow (i.e when you run your app in an emulator)?

Comment: You put your external libraries manually there. It's better to read on the homepage of the library you are using for instructions on how add it to your project.